# Is it possible to disconnect from a Meteor server at will?

Tags: websocket, meteor

I'd like to make an app that only checks in periodically for updates, and doesn't require a connection to be open the whole time it's active. Is that possible without a hack?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve by only checking periodically for updates?

Comment: Even without a constant connection, Meteor does a lot of nice stuff for you. There are also tons of apps (mobile especially) that would only want to synchronize with the server intermittently (mail clients, news apps, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disconnect the client from the server. The most you could do is stop running Meteor on the server and then periodically start it up and shut it down again, which I wouldn't recommend.

Meteor is really designed to just be connected all the time. Everything from live templates to client-side Minimongo caching depends on that connection working, so if you disabled it, you would intentionally be breaking a fundamental layer of Meteor that is supposed to save you a lot of trouble.